# Difficulty in selection specific row and merge with specific column

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file which i have a data like this

Textfile1

```
?Cricket|Batsman|EK
Batsman play cricket for batting
?Cricket|Football|E9
Sequence unavailable
?Cricket|Hockey|EN
Sequence unavailable
```

I want to copy only the data which have `Sequence unavailable` along with question number which is given in last column `EN`

Required Output

```
Sequence unavailable|E9
Sequence unavailable|EN
```

I don't have idea how to select only the specific data of `Sequence unavailable` , i tag all the last column but difficulty in selecting only the `Sequence unavailable` with its question number

Comment: Will it always be every two lines?

Comment: Please add what you have tried to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
lastline = None

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if not lastline:
            lastline = line.rstrip('\n')
            continue
        if line.rstrip('\n') == 'Sequence unavailable':
            _, _, id = lastline.split('|')
            print 'Sequence unavailable|' + id
        lastline = None
```

Answer (score 0):

How difficult its for you to join the 2nd,4,6th row to first row with "|" sepeartor.
If its not that hard then I have a quick and dirty solution.

the modified data looks like..

> Game|Player|Inning|Result
>
> Cricket|Batsman|EK|Batsman play cricket for batting
>
> Cricket|Football|E9|Sequence unavailable
>
> Cricket|Hockey|EN|Sequence unavailable

And the code looks like...

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv("test.txt",sep="|")

c = a[a["Result"] != "Sequence unavailable"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you only want the data when it's "Sequence unavailable"? Then maybe this will help you:

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    s = f.read()

output, lines = [], (line for line in s.split("\n"))

for line in lines:
    if line.startswith("?"):
        data = next(lines)
        if data == "Sequence unavailable":
            output.append("{data}|{qn}".format(data=data, qn=line.split("|")[-1]))

with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in output:
        f.write(line + "\n")
```